# Switched embedded video iframe cause page unresponsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, frontend

I have multiple third-party iframes and would like to filter selected the item to switch to specific iframe. Most of my iframes it's like a documentation except there's one iframe which it embeded video element in the background. Then, whenever I tried to switched this iframe to another iframe, my page became unresponsive. I wonder what may be casuing? It's because there are too much data process at the same time?

I tried to use pause method to pause the video in the iframe's background, but it won't work.

Comment: What happens if you remove the iframe from the DOM? (And then create a new one for the next video.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.